# CakePHP query binding

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create a sql statement with cakePHP 3.6.10:

```
SELECT id FROM table_xy WHERE (status != 1 OR name IS NULL) AND id IN(1,2,3);
```

Now, copying from the sophistated examples in the [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions) I got this:

```
$userIds = [2,212,232];
$table = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('TableXY');
$query = $table->find()
    ->select(['id'])
    ->where(function(QueryExpression $exp) {
        $orConditions = $exp->or_(function($or) {
            return $or->isNull('name')
                ->notEq('status', 1);
         });
         return $exp
            ->add($orConditions)
            ->in('id', ':id');
        })
        ->bind(':id', $userIds, 'int[]');
$results = $query->all();
```

This results in an error, saying "unknown type int[]". But this is exactly the same as described in the [documentation](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html)

```
$query->bind(':id', [1, 2, 3], 'int[]');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of such sophisticated example, you can try like this:

```
// an array is not automatically converted
$result =  $this->table_xy->find('all')->where(['id IN' => $userIds, 
     'OR' => [
                   'status !=' => 1,
                   'name is NULL'
             ]
    ])->select(['id']);
```

[CAKEPHP > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions%20%22%22)

Comment: The crucial point is that I want to apply a filter ".. id IN (..)". So extending your code with
    ->where(['id IN ' => $userIds,
gives me what I need
Thank you

Comment: @kwazineuf In Cakephp If you pass array in condition then it automatically consider it as IN clause. Anyway don't forget to accept the answer. It will help other.

Comment: I can not confirm that cakePHP automatically uses an IN-clause when an array is passed in a where condition. An error is thrown: "Cannot convert value of type 'array' to integer" - thanks anyway